# Set column type as data on Kendo Grid in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that is generated with javascript. I have no datasource as the data is on the page, then the javascript generates the grid over it.  I am trying to set a column as type Date, but when I do the column just shows up empty.

This is the script for generating the kendo grid

```
var grid = $("#punches").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 15,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        PunchDay: { type: 'date' }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        sortable: true,
        selectable: "multiple",
        pageable: true,
        filterable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        groupable: true,
        resizable: true
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

The `PunchDay` column is showing empty when I set the type.  I believe it has something to do with the data in that column being set like this

`@FieldTranslation.ToShortDate(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PunchDay).ToString())`

Since its a string and not a date format.  However, I don't have a way around this.  My grid code is

```html
<table class="table" id="punches">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("ID", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("ID", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("EmployeeName", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("EmployeeName", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("PunchDay", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("PunchDay", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("PunchIn", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("PunchIn", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("PunchOut", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("PunchOut", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("Adjustment Time", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("Adjustment Time", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("Adjustment Description", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("Adjustment Description", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("WorkHours", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("WorkHours", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                @*<th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Inactive)
                </th>*@
                <th title="@FieldTranslation.GetLabel("Department", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)">
                    @FieldTranslation.GetLabel("Department", GlobalVariables.LanguageID)
                </th>
                <th width="125px;" class="hidden-filter">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @FieldTranslation.ToShortDate(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PunchDay).ToString())
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @FieldTranslation.ToShortTime(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PunchIn).ToString())
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @FieldTranslation.ToShortTime(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PunchOut).ToString())
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdjustTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdjustDescr)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkHours)
                    </td>
                    @*<td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Inactive)
                    </td>*@
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("EditTime", "TimePunches", new {id = item.ID, flt = ViewBag.FLT})" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit fa fa-pencil fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("PunchLogIndex", "TimePunches", new {id = item.ID, flt = ViewBag.FLT})" title="Punch Log"><i class="icon-purple fa fa-book fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("PunchRequestIndex", "TimePunches", new { punchId = item.ID, flt = ViewBag.FLT })" title="See Change Request Log"><i class="icon-niagara fa fa-list fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" id="delete" data-id="@item.ID" data-client="@item.ClientID"><i class="icon-red fa fa-times fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

What can I do to get my dates to reappear?

Comment: Did you try to keep it as string and add columns part?

Comment: I did try that @soham and it seems to just break the grid. Doesn't filter or do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add columns part like this

```
var grid = $("#punches").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 15,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    PunchDay: { type: 'date' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    sortable: true,
    selectable: "multiple",
    pageable: true,
    filterable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    groupable: true,
    resizable: true
},
columns: [
    { field: "PunchDay", title: "PunchDay", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" },
    ...
]).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: I've tried this. it just breaks the grid for some odd reason.  Doesn't load filters or anything

Comment: @TheDizzle It should not break the grid. Did you add all fields in columns in place of `...` part?

Comment: I did include all the columns